# Remove an entire child from Firebase using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'd like to write a function to remove an entire child from Firebase. I'm using XCode 10 and swift 3+.

I have all the user info of the child I'd like to delete so I assume the best call would be to iterate through every child and test for the matching sub child value but it would be great if there was a faster way.
Thanks for the help!

Heres what I'd like to delete

[image]

I assume testing for epoch time then removing the whole node would be ideal. Also not sure how to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand you don't have access to the key of the node you want do delete. Is that right? Why not? If you use the "observe()" function on a FIRDatabaseQuery object, each returned object should come with a key and a value.

Having a key it is easy to remove a node, as stated in the [Firebase official guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).

From the linked guide,

> Delete data
>
> The simplest way to delete data is to call removeValue on a reference
>   to the location of that data.
>
> You can also delete by specifying nil as the value for another write
>   operation such as setValue or updateChildValues. You can use this
>   technique with updateChildValues to delete multiple children in a
>   single API call.

So, you could try:

```
FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference(withPath: "Forum").child(key).removeValue()
```

or

```
FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference(withPath: "Forum").child(key).setValue(nil)
```

If you can't get the key in any way, what you said about "iterating" through the children of the node could be done by using a query. Here's some example code, supposing you want all forum posts by Jonahelbaz:

```
return FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference(withPath: "Forum").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "Jonahelbaz").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let forumPosts = snapshot.value as? [String: [String: AnyObject]] {
        for (key, _) in forumPosts  {
                FirebaseDatabase.Database.database().reference(withPath: "Forum").child(key).removeValue()
        }
    }
})
```

Here you create a sorted query using as reference "username" then you ask only for the forum posts where "username" are equal to Johanelbaz. You know the returned snapshot is an Array, so now you iterate through the array and use the keys for deleting the nodes.

This way of deleting isn't very good because you might get several posts with the same username and would delete them all. The ideal case would be to obtain the exact key of the forum post you want to delete.

Comment: That worked great! I think i'm going to use Epoch time to delete it because you likely will never have more than one post submitted at the same time (theoretically). Heres the only hiccup though. What that did was delete every post EXCEPT the one with username Jonahelbaz

Comment: Correction to that last comment. I had a mistake in my previous code that caused this. It works perfectly now! thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Oh now I understand what you meant about using the epoch time... Well, it is sort of a unique key... :-)